# How can I fix a script that allows to import selenium in Python debugger but not when I call the script itself?

Tags: macos, python

I wrote a Python script to use Selenium to open FireFox and scrape stuff off a web page.

Here's the minimal version of code that works in the debugger.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
#from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
#from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

quit()
```

However, it fails when I call it via an AppleScriptTask.
If I comment out the selenium line the call via AppleScriptTask works fine.

It works great in the Visual Studio debugger on my Mac mini but when I try to call the script, as I do other Python scripts, from Excel in VBA it fails.

Can anyone offer tips on how to sort this out or fix my script?

Comment: How does it "fail"?  Add the actual error message to your question.

Comment: Unfortunately, Apple doesn't play well with Microsoft so the only error msg I get is that the AppleScriptTask failed with this message:  "Run-time error '5':"  "Invalid procedure call or argument". I can say that the problem seems to me that it can't find the Selenium module even though it is found in the debugger.

Comment: Is this fundamentally the same question you posed today? Excel can’t trigger this automation chain?

Comment: Yes it is,  I was hoping to present the problem from a different angle and hopefully spark a wider discussion.

Comment: Mike, to answer your second question, I have to use AppleScriptTask to invoke the Python script.  It's a roundabout way to call it so I don't get the exact error message from the Python script; instead I get a message from AppleScriptTask saying only that there was a problem but no information on what the problem was.  Regardless of the cause, it always just returns the "Run-time error '5'" message.  It was only by trial and error that I figured out the problem was the import of Selenium.

Comment: this thread explains how I call a Python script from VBA. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67994030/how-is-applescripttask-called-from-excel-365-vba-on-mac-mini-running-big-sur