# How can I ensure that Excel can import my pip-installed python libraries?

Tags: macos, ms-office, python, sonoma, visual-studio-code

I have a script that imports Selenium WebDriver and it runs fine in VisualStudio debugger but fails when I call it from an Excel module because it can't find the Selenium module.  Here's the code stub:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
quit()
```

If I comment out the selenium import line it runs when I call it from Excel.

I assume these are running in different environments.

I installed Selenium via pip in a terminal window which made it available to the debugger but not to whatever runs when I call it from Excel.

Any ideas about how to check and fix this?

Comment: Hi Phil. To avoid down votes, consider editing  this so only one question is asked per question. Hopefully this and [your other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/467491/5472) get you some traction

Comment: Thanks Mike.  I'm new at this.  I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: Being new is a womderful place from which to learn. Excellent clarity now IMO. No excel for me, but I’ll post an answer if I can dig something up that might help get started on an answer.

Comment: Does Excel package a `python` interpreter?   What python are you installing `Selenium` in?

Comment: Python 3.10.9.  No, Excel has no direct way to invoke a Python script that I'm aware of on the Mac.  I have to run it indirectly by using AppleScriptTask to indirectly invoke it.  It is a bit of a kludgy way to get the job done but a few generations ago, Microsoft dropped support for running Internet Explorer directly from VBA so this was the best solution I could come up with.  I have used Python scripts to call APIs with no problem it is only when I try to import the Selenium modules that I have an issue.  Beautiful soup was no problem.

Comment: Check out this thread to see how I call a Python script from VBA.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67994030/how-is-applescripttask-called-from-excel-365-vba-on-mac-mini-running-big-sur

Comment: What `python`?  Not what version of `python`.  macOS packaged python2.x up through Monterey 12.3, and does no longer.  The CLT packages a version of `python3`, but then you have to have the CLT installed.  The stackoverflow link you reference in your other question tries to call `/usr/local/bin/python3`.

Comment: How can I check that Marc?  At the Terminal window prompt I typed in Python3 and hit enter.  That string above with the version number is part of what was returned.  Here's the  full string:  "Python 3.10.9 (main, Mar  1 2023, 12:33:47) [Clang 14.0.6 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information."                      I think it's Anaconda but not sure.

Comment: Marc, I'm sorry to say I'm really a Python newbie and I have no idea what you mean by CLT.  I tried looking it up but all I come up with are pages about Central Limit Theorem.  Would you please explain.  Would this explain  the fact that the script works without the import of Selenium but fails when I try to import   Selenium?

Comment: @phil Please add whatever AS fragment you are using to your question.

Comment: Marc, I finally figured out that CLT probably means Xcode Command Line Tools but I still have no idea what that would have  to do with my selenium issue.  I also have no idea what an "AS fragment" is.   For most of my life I've used Windows.  IOS is as new to me as Python.